# Get items from request.FILES

Tags: django, request

I tried to get items by `request.FILES`: from input `<input type='file' name='images' multiple>` I recieve to django views the data:

```
<MultiValueDict: {
u'images': [
<InMemoryUploadedFile: Men_Mother_Boys_Little_girls_Smi.jpg (image/jpeg)>,
<InMemoryUploadedFile: tumblr_p4fq65rkPh1uc0ho8o1_1280.jpg (image/jpeg)>, 
<InMemoryUploadedFile: tumblr_nxq18wYT4l1uc0ho8o1_500.jpg (image/jpeg)>, 
<InMemoryUploadedFile: ddc4790b00ee3c8d51c106afa76a4dc7.jpg (image/jpeg)>, 
<InMemoryUploadedFile: 9961f0d0ea1b54cdd9d4a2c58a66c6be.jpg (image/jpeg)>
]}>
```

I try get the list of files:

```
images = self.request.FILES.get('images', None)
```

But in images always I receive just single `<InMemoryUploadedFile>`, although I expect list of `InMemoryUploadedFile`. I checked:

```
    print(type(self.request.FILES))  #<MultiValueDict: {u'images': [<InMemoryUploadedFile:
    print(type(images))              #InMemoryUploadedFile
```

I find this rather atypical for behavior a dictionary. Maybe this is a pre-planned behavior intended to receive for single file. Is that how it should be?

Comment: You should use `getlist`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified in the output, you are working with a `MultiValueDict`, so you can use the [**`getlist`** method [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/utils/datastructures.py#L141):

```
images = self.request.FILES.getlist('images', None)
```